# Deselect Objects by Type with Python

Tags: python, objects

I have a mesh, and it has children. One of it's children is an Empty. I know there is a way to select an object by type using Python (and there's a button for it too) and it's this:

`bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='EMPTY')`

I was wondering if there was a way to deselect an object by type. Basically, I want to select the children of the mesh, then deselect the empty.

Thanks!

Comment: How about select inverse, select by type, select inverse?

Comment: That won't work, because I have other models in the scene. I just want the children of the current mesh without selecting the parent. I'll try to use one of the answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest not to use `bpy.ops` and instead access the selection directly.

```
# assume you the active object is the parent
for obj in bpy.context.object.children:
    if obj.type != 'EMPTY':
        obj.select = True
```

This is a little more clever, you can do it recursively (to select children's children).

```
def select_children_recursive(obj_parent):
    for obj in obj_parent.children:
        select_children_recursive(obj)
        if obj.type != 'EMPTY':
            obj.select = True
# call the function
select_children_recursive(bpy.context.object)
```

Similar to above but caller can define types not to select

```
def select_children_recursive(obj_parent, type_mask):
    for obj in obj_parent.children:
        select_children_recursive(obj)
        if obj.type not in type_mask:
            obj.select = True
# call the function
select_children_recursive(bpy.context.object, {'EMPTY', 'LAMP'})
```

Comment: The first code box did the trick!

Comment: Well, I am still having issues. It won't allow me to use bpy.context in my importer script. Any ideas?

Comment: Please elaborate on **"It won't allow me"**

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. :P I get an error that says "Context is incorrect". I've searched around, but no luck...

Comment: @rioforce, Id need to see a link to full script and full stack trace. but this is probably another question.

Answer (score 3):

For your use case, something like this will work

```
import bpy

# go through the children of the parent object
for child in bpy.data.objects["Cube"].children:
    # if the child is not an empty, select it
    if child.type != 'EMPTY':
        child.select = True
```