# how can i select all objects by type using python

Tags: python, scripting

How can i select all objects by type using python scripting. I am trying to select all empties in my scene.

I tried using `bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='EMPTY')` but thats doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blender 2.7x

```
import bpy

objects = bpy.context.scene.objects

for obj in objects:
    obj.select = obj.type == "EMPTY"
```

Blender 2.8x

```
import bpy

objects = bpy.context.scene.objects

for obj in objects:
    obj.select_set(obj.type == "EMPTY")
```

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10480/deselect-objects-by-type-with-python) for more info.

Comment: Nitpick: in the for loop you can just do `obj.select = obj.type == "EMPTY"`

Answer (score 2):

```
item='EMPTY'
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type=item)
```

where `item` can take any of the following values according to [this documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.type):

```
[‘MESH’, ‘CURVE’, ‘SURFACE’, ‘META’, ‘FONT’, ‘HAIR’, ‘POINTCLOUD’, ‘VOLUME’, ‘GPENCIL’, ‘ARMATURE’, ‘LATTICE’, ‘EMPTY’, ‘LIGHT’, ‘LIGHT_PROBE’, ‘CAMERA’, ‘SPEAKER’]
```

Comment: It's recommended to avoid operators if you can. @doakey3's answer is preferred.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Operators are slower, create (possibly unnecessary) undo steps, are harder to integrate with other code, and are more sensitive to the content in which they are used.